# How to set-up Rails form select for a collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a code base that I'm not very familiar with, specifically Haml. I need to set-up a select dropdown to select a user.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
def edit
  @franchise = Franchise.find params[:id]
  @ab_reps = User.where role: "admin-ab"
  authorize! :update, @franchise
end
```

I have the following code in my form (that doesn't currently work):

```
= f.select :ab_rep, options_for_select(@ab_reps, f.object.ab_rep), {prompt: "AB Representative"}, {label: false, right_class: "col-sm-10", class: "ab-rep-field"}
```

Couple questions:

1.) @ab_reps is an array of user objects. I have the following method in my user model:

```
def name
 [first_name, last_name].compact.join(" ")
end
```

How do I get the select to display the user names instead of the user objects (which it currently does) ?

2.) Is my current set-up even close to being correct?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, you need to provide the methods for the option value and the option text, as well as the collection which in your case is @ab_reps. Additionally you can provide a hash for prompts and for html_options such as class names, which you've done.

Rails has a few different helpers you can use for select tags including options_from_collection_for_select. I've used collection_select often, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select

```
= f.collection_select :ab_rep, @ab_reps, :id, :name, {prompt: "AB Representative"}
```